# Linux kernel module calculate hashes of devices

Tags: c, linux, io, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm currently writing a Kernel module (out of pure curiosity).

Now I would like to calculate a hash of my whole `/boot` partition (`/dev/sda3`).

I thought of opening the file `/dev/sda3`, and hashing its content, but as I searched arround how this could be archived within a kernel module I only came across people stating that one should not perform I/O operations in a kernel module.

Now to my question: Is there a way of reading the data of this partition or do I actually have to write a driver for this?

In case it is relevant: the Kernel module shall be loaded on boot before the encrypt module gets loaded.

Comment: Why do this from the kernel? Much easier from userspace.

Comment: As I stated above I would like to do this right after the boot process before my discs get decrypted (so before the encrypt hook gets executed).

Comment: You may try to open (`filp_open`) `/dev/sda3` as a file and read (`filp_read`) it. Or use `generic_make_request` for access block device directly. Loading you module before the encrypt module is other question.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you, I'll try that out as soon as possible and then give feedback!

Comment: Hey, I ended up using vfs.